# Would alpha decay taste sour?

Tags: radioactivity

If someone were foolish and/or brave enough to build a device to focus the alpha decay products from a radioactive sample, then point it at their tongue through their open mouth, would it taste sour, assuming there were sufficient helium nuclei?

On one hand, I can imagine the eletro-negativity of the alpha decay products being high enough that it would act as an acid and trigger the sour-response in the taste bud.

On the other hand, I can imagine it not tasting like anything for the two following reasons:

1. The helium nucleus might quickly gain electrons and become inert before it 
   had a chance to trigger a neural response
2. The helium nucleus might cause enough damage to the taste buds to render them ineffective

I know this is a bit of a silly question, but what would alpha-decay taste like?

Comment: "Sufficient proton flux"? What do you mean by that? (I am reminded of Urey's paper on the taste of heavy water - it didn't taste different - but would not recommend performing this experiment).

Comment: @JonCuster I was thinking about rewording that... I simply meant, "a large enough quantity helium nuclei"

Comment: Fair enough, but alphas aren't protons, hence my question. I don't see how an ionized alpha particle would act as an acid. Sure, it wants to grab somebody's spare electron, but that isn't an acid.

Comment: Yes, but they contain protons, and no electrons to balance them out. Acids like to grab electrons from other chemicals. However, if you do not believe a helium nucleus would act like an acid, seems like that would be a good start to an answer ;)

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer: When people ask for clarification in comments, the thing to do is to edit the question, not answer in comments.

Comment: All nuclei contain protons. Most contain neutrons as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely thinking of protons having a sour taste, [since we experience H$^{+}$ as sour](https://www.pnas.org/content/107/51/21955) (actually, it is H$_3$O$^+$ in water). However, alpha particles either zip through the sensory cells and just act as ionizing radiation or slow down and then behave like tasteless helium.

[Apparently](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-people-taste-metal-in-their-mouths-at-Chernobyl-during-the-disaster) ionizing radiation does produce [a metallic taste](http://chernobylplace.com/does-the-radiation-taste-and-smell/) when it is strong enough, perhaps due to breaking down lipids. There may be an ozone smell too. A strong alpha source might achieve that.

(There may be other effects too. Depletion of some types of taste sensory cells is likely: radiation therapy commonly affects taste acuity. Charged particles can trigger neural firing too.)

I am more curious about the taste of a proton beam. It might be sour, but most likely just acts as intense ionizing radiation. [Anatoli Bugorski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoli_Bugorski) did experience it as brightness, but it did not pass through his mouth as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking, if H+ is sour, perhaps He+ is very sour. Thanks for the thoughtful answer

Answer (score 2):

No. As pointed out by Jon Custer in comments, an alpha particle is not a proton. It's a helium nucleus, and helium is chemically unreactive, so it has no taste.